# Unordered configuration space with non-distinct points

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Consider a topological space $X$, a natural number $n>0$ and
the quotient topological space $Q_n(X)$ of $X^n$ by the equivalence relation : $x\sim y$ if and only if
there is a permutation $\sigma$ such that $x_i=y_{\sigma(i)}$.

I've seen many results on the usual unordered configuration space (where we only consider distincts points), and my question is basically : what is known about $Q_n(X)$ ?
Have these spaces been studied ? For example, is $Q_n(\mathbb{R^2})$ the classifying space of a known group ? Do we know how to compute the fundamental group of $Q_n(\mathbb{R^2})$ ?

Comment: This is the symmetric power $\operatorname{Sym}^n(X)$ of $X$ - the quotient of $X^n$ by the action of the symmetric group of order $n$ (btw, their union is the Ran space of $X$ which is contractible).

Comment: See for example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118458/homology-of-symmetric-product  or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_product_(topology)